# How to use ArcMap python to parse int from a (part of a) string?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, string, integer

I'm using the ArcMap Field Calculator to parse the year from a field `GLVertra_1` with values like this:

**1992/05/13**

or more generally YYYY/MM/DD, but also containing empty cells (or cells appearing empty).
My approach is `JAHRNU = stringToInt( !GLVertra_1! )` with the function:

```
def stringToInt(s):
  if not s:
    return 0
  else:
    return int(s[0:4])
```

This results in the error `invalid literal for int() with base 10:`, which I assumed comes from empty strings, so I introduced the check for empty strings (`if not s`), but it still doesn't work.

The answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286213/changing-string-to-integer-using-arcgis-field-calculator) (automatic casting) doesn't work for me, if I don't cast it explicitly as `int()`, I get an error (`The value type is incompatible with the field type`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the cells may appear empty, but actually have "spaces" in them (" "). Extending the check for empty strings according to answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty) (scroll down for more elaborate answers than the accepted one) accomodates for this case.

This worked:

```
def stringToInt(s):
  if not bool(s and not s.isspace()):
    return 0
  else:
    return int(s[0:4])
```

The explicit typecast `int()` can also be omitted, ArcPy/ArcMap does the casting itself.

Comment: You could also use try/except